# Quadratic formula solver does not give the correct result

Tags: python, quadratic

This quadratic formula solver is not working. 
I am not able to find out why.

Here is the code (python):

```
    def binomio(a,b,c):
        return (b**2)-(4*a*c)
    def raiz1(a,b,c):
        bn = binomio(a,b,c)
        x = ((-b+(bn ** (0.5)))/(2*a))
        return round(x,2)
    def raiz2(a,b,c):
        bn = binomio(a,b,c)
        y = ((-b-(bn**(0.5)))/(2*a))
        return round(y,2)
    def main():
        a = float(input("a:0"))
        b = float(input("b:0"))
        c = float(input("c:0"))
        if (binomio(a,b,c) < 0):
           print("0")
        elif (binomio(a,b,c) = 0):
            print("1",raiz1(a,b,c))
        else:
             if (raiz1(a,b,c) > raiz2(a,b,c)):
                 print("2:",raiz2(a,b,c),raiz1(a,b,c))
             else:
                 print("2:",raiz1(a,b,c),raiz2(a,b,c))
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The program can be simplified. Everything works.

```py
def discriminant(a, b, c):
    return (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)


def roots(a, b, c):
    d = discriminant(a, b, c)
    if d < 0:
        return None
    return (-b + d ** 0.5) / (2 * a), (-b - d ** 0.5) / (2 * a)


def main():
    a = float(input("a: "))
    b = float(input("b: "))
    c = float(input("c: "))

    res = roots(a, b, c)
    if res is not None:
        if round(res[0], 5) == round(res[1], 5):
            res = res[0]
    print('roots:', res)


main()
```

**P.S.**

For the future: this service is not educational in nature. How to program the solution of a quadratic equation in any programming language can be easily found in Google.